# Execute pre-packaged Eclipse application on Mac

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded a pre-packaged Eclipse installation to my Mac (not from the Eclipse website), and it has a "exec" file called Eclipse which MacOS suggests to open with Terminal. In addition, there's an eclipse.ini, and other files and directories. How do i actually open this Eclipse?
Note - I am working on a project that has a number of plugins that have to be compatible with each other, hence i was told to use this pre-packaged Eclipse installation.

Comment: Any chance the packager is around to answer that question?

Comment: If it is all in an `Eclipse.app` directory then it is a complete macOS application and you run like you would run any other macOS app. Finder will show the directory as just `Eclipse` (without the `.app`)